# Problems in substack

Tags: livecode

I create main stack and Substack, also I create a button in sub stack for performing find a word in scrolling field(the scrolling field is main stack).
If coded as

```
on mouseUp
    find "Work" in field "text"--Here "text" is a scrolling field placed in main stack
        end mouseUp
```

This code for button placed in Substack. why it's not working? is it any alternative way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell where the field is:

```
on mouseUp
find "Work" in field "text" on stack "mainstack" -- your stack's name, or use stack id XXXX 
end mouseUp
```